# What are some possible reasons that a heating oil rep would be anticipating oil prices falling?

Tags: budget, crude-oil

We are planning on prebuying heating oil this year to avoid high costs if the price rises over the winter.

We can buy now, or wait until fall.  The person I spoke to over the phone said she would advise us to wait, because "we expect prices will go down after summer."  But this doesn't make sense to me.  The price of literally everything is rising with no end in sight, plus the demand will be higher in fall when everyone starts filling up.

What are some possible reasons that a heating oil rep would be anticipating oil prices falling?

Comment: Novices always panic and "buy high sell low".  "No end in sight" is basically the financial version of "hold my beer" lol.

Comment: If prices fall you could be kicking yourself for not getting a better deal, if they rise you could have a cold winter. The gamble is up to you, the heating oil rep does have a vested interest in avoiding panic buying so take their advice with a pinch of salt.

Comment: Can you make that more clear? If you're really asking about a heating oil rep, who is he that you base your financial planning on his opinion? If you're actually asking a finance consultant with specialist knowledge of the heating oil market, why not say so?

Answer (score 43):

Heating oil is at record high prices. It's not unreasonable to think that the price will go down at some point, especially if production increases due to high prices. However, generally the cheapest time to buy oil is the summer when demand is low, so that is working against you.

Now, they could be lying, or they could just be wrong, or it could go down later than they predict - no one knows for sure.

The question is, are *you* willing to make that bet? The point of pre-buying is to lock in prices, taking out price risk. If you do not buy, and prices go even higher, could your budget afford it? Or would you adjust usage to reduce your cost? If you do pre-buy, and prices go down, would you be upset that you overpaid, or just be comforted that your prices were locked in either way?

If it were me, I would be hesitant to pre-buy at all-time high prices. But you do what makes sense for your budget.

Comment: An all-time high price typically is no longer an all-time high price (meaning the price continues going higher, repeatedly setting a new all-time high price).

Comment: @7529 Look at the [price of HO](https://www.eia.gov/dnav/pet/hist/LeafHandler.ashx?n=PET&s=W_EPD2F_PRS_NUS_DPG&f=W) over the last 20 years - prices have gone up and down significantly. Yes the _trend_ is to go up but it's not unreasonable to think that the price will go down.

Comment: @DStanley If question was posted in 2010, the OP would have to wait 5 years to buy oil at a lower price. The fact the price of oil is at a historical high now, doesn't mean it will drop before it rises again, and doesn't mean it will be a short period of time before it falls. (Example 2011). You may be correct that it's "reasonable" to think the price will go down, the question is when.

Comment: HO was not at an all-time high in 2010. If they had locked in in 2008 (another time of great uncertainty), they would have paid double what they would have paid if they had not locked in. And I'm not saying it _will_ go down, I'm saying there's valid reasons to think that it _might_, and less compelling reasons to think that it will definitely go up. If it's me I'm not locking in at high prices. I'm taking a chance that it will go down (knowing that I might be wrong).

Answer (score 31):

> What are some possible reasons that a heating oil rep would be
> anticipating oil prices falling?

The script they are reading from tells them to say this.  If they will make more money if the prices do X, then they will tell you they will do the opposite of X in a few months.

Don't ask the person you are making a bet with, which option you should pick.

Comment: Why would they say the opposite of something merely because it would make them more money? Isn't there more to it than that? They would make money if there was an ice age, but that doesn't lead them to say "there won't be an ice age in a few months"

Comment: @user253751 Seriously? "Why would someone say something if it would make them money?"

Comment: @Brondahl I don't see how saying the opposite of something that could make them money would help them make money. I make money when you give me $5, but me saying "you won't give me $5" doesn't help me make any money.

Comment: I don't think the sales rep can really know what the price is going to do in the future. Much less in a specific timeframe. Otherwise, she would be extremely rich trading oil futures (same applies to the company she represents).

Comment: @user253751 If the company experts believe that the price will go up, then the company may have made a bet that the price will go up, now they need their customers to act in a certain way. That is the answer that the person on the phone is told to say.

Comment: @mhoran_psprep Why do they need their customers to act in *this particular* way if they made *this particular* bet? If they bought oil futures, they can sell the oil futures without involving their customers...

Comment: @user253751 We don't know what the company did. What we do know is what the company told the homeowner. That answer will not be the one that will lose the company money.

Comment: I don't think this makes too much sense. If prices go up even further, they just lost a customer that will avoid them out of spite. If prices go down, they make less money. ((obviously, assuming something resembling competition, which might not be a given))

Comment: If the company anticipates the price of oil to keep rising, it would be in their best financial interests to get the customers to buy in the future (when they can sell for more) instead of buying it now (when it's cheaper)

Comment: @user253751 it is impossible to sell anything without customers. In order to sell, you need someone to buy. If the company thinks they will make more money by selling later, they have good reason to convince their customers to wait in buying.

Comment: Companies selling heating oil expect years, maybe decades, of repeat custom. Screwing a customer for a small benefit one year is bad business.

Comment: Companies also like predictable income. That's why they allow customers to lock in prices even if they expect prices to increase -- that reliable income stream is valuable. "A bird in the hand is worth two in the bush". They even give discounts if you make a long-term contract.

Comment: But an appropriately priced "bet" should leave the person offering it more or less *indifferent* to which side you bet on - the house never offers a bet where either side has positive expected value, or else it may lose money. The house *does not care* what bet you make at the roulette table, since they're all priced accordingly. Put another way, if the heating company really stands to gain significantly by having you opt out of the pre-buy option, they should either not be offering pre-buy *at all*, or they should be charging more for it.

Comment: @Luke They could also make that bet with oil futures, without affecting their customers.

Comment: @user253751 Your original comment might just be poorly phrased?   I don't know if the sales rep will make more money if prices go up, or if they have any real idea what will happen to prices.  But "Why would they say the opposite of something merely because it would make them more money?" really is a silly question.  If they did know the price would go up and they would make money, the sales rep would get more commission, and money is probably the most popular reason to lie.   You might as well ask why poker isn't played with your cards face-up.

Comment: @JasonGoemaat The answer says "If they will make more money if the prices do X, then they will tell you they will do the opposite of X in a few months." and in my opinion this is just not correct as a general case.

Answer (score 13):

It's a good idea to plan your heating budget in advance.

What would be even wiser would be to plan how you could reduce your oil consumption, or remove it altogether. Oil prices are expected to stay volatile. If you gamble on oil-prices, you might win or lose some money in the short-term. If you keep on gambling every year, you will lose in the long-term. And in 10 years, you'll still be stuck with an inefficient, dirty and possibly banned oil burner.

If you have disposable income now, you should take a good look at insulating your home, or replacing your heating system with something more environmentally-friendly and not dependent on fossil-fuels.

Answer (score 6):

Good plan to reduce risk usually is to diversify it.

- Firstly (although not directly asked), you may want to reduce your dependence on oil for heating. So for example invest in better heating insulation, buy a [Heat pump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_pump) for backup, perhaps some solar panels etc.
  That way, even if oil prices skyrocket even more (even as high as to become unaffordable to you; or even if the situation happens that there is not enough oil to fill the demand), you could still get by without it.
- Secondly, split the risk in oil price change. So you may (for example) buy 50% of the oil now, and 50% later. So even if the price later goes up by 40%, you'd only be hit by 20% increase (but similarly, if the price goes down 20%, you'd only save 10%). Of course you can choose other ratios instead of 50-50 (depending on how comfortable you are to price volatility) as well as buy it in more then two installments (but note that there is extra cost to each installment)

As for the theoretical forecast:

> What are some possible reasons that a heating oil rep would be anticipating oil prices falling?

Firstly, the person might be lying, either to increase their company profits, or to avoid spreading panic leading to their demise (for example, if they don't actually have enough oil to sell).

Or, they could be speaking their true belief, based on many economic analyses. That would likely get more extensive on economics SE or politics SE. There are many possible reasons: supply and demand (and many countries involved), possible government measures, weather forecast, estimates of political (de-)escalation with Russia, and other more-or less crystal-ball attempts of predicting the future.

You could **ask** them why they expect such price changes, and then you'd have one more datapoint to do research on and eventually decide on your tactics. (for which I've suggested relatively safe methods above)

But note: **vast majority of such predictions would always be proven wrong** -- as there is ***only one outcome that would come true***, and all others would be shown as false. It might depend on how good economic analytics the person you spoke to was (although if they were good at it, I'd suspect they would be working in economic forecast sector instead), but what would actually happen to prices it is likely to be based more on your luck than on all forecasts in the world.

Basically, treat their advice in no higher regard than if your favorite news portal recommended you that now is the time to buy (or sell) Tesla or Apple stock, or sell (or buy) Bitcoin.

Answer (score 3):

Oil prices are high mostly because of the Russian invasion of Ukraine, this has driven market fears of supply problems, and desire in the West to avoid buying Russian oil (pointlessly, because Russia just sells that oil to China, etc. at higher prices now).

But global oil production hasn't changed much, and is expected to outstrip consumption through the latter part of this year. This is expected to lead to [a modest fall in prices](https://www.eia.gov/outlooks/steo/report/global_oil.php).

Comment: Why would Russia be able to sell that oil to China **at higher prices** than before? There's suddenly much less global demand for **Russian** oil (since western countries are hesitant to buy it) which should drive Russian oil prices down (while at the same time increasing the price of non-Russian oil).

Comment: @Dreamer: Because oil are sold on commodity markets. Russia is selling at a discount vs. Brent crude but that's still a significantly higher price than it was before. Go and look it up.

Comment: Also as China is swapping its oil imports to be primarily Russian, it is importing less from everywhere else.  This drop in demand is likely to result in a a drop in non-Russian oil prices

Comment: Actually they're having to give away oil at fire sale prices to anyone who will buy, that means China, India and Syria are getting bargain prices.  And because of the very high ruble, the Euros/dollars they are paying don't buy many rubles to pay their workers with.  Sucks for Russia.

Answer (score 1):

Large, liquid markets like oil are efficient and market participants make use of almost all available information when engaging in price discovery. Predicting what the price will be in the future is not realistic for the ordinary person. What a sales rep said on the phone should certainly not be treated as a market signal.

The rep has no basis to be anticipating any kind of price action, so the logical conclusion is that she is taking unsupported assumptions as fact. There is little point in trying to divine what was on her mind.

That said, if I ran a company that buys a commodity in bulk and then resells it to retail customers at profit, and I ever caught my rep talking people out of buying at a record high price, I'd fire her on the spot. Seems more likely to me like the company thinks the prices will go up, so they're having the rep tell you to wait, so you have to pay even more later - after summer - when it's getting cold and people start buying the oil, driving prices up.

Comment: That's not true. Since oil is (also) traded as a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_contract , that company can very well already have a contract for receiving oil X months into the future at a price already determined today. So they can very well know that the oil they'll sell in X months will be cheaper for them than the oil they are currently selling - and insomuch as market forces are in effect, would reduce consumer prices in X months accordingly.

Comment: @Dreamer and what about the price when they sell in X months plus 1 day?  Then there will be new contracts and new pricing and so on. If I go to a gas station and ask the guy at the cash register if gas prices are going up or down tomorrow no one would be answering as though he’s intimately aware of the price hedging strategy of the oil company.

Comment: I agree with the first paragraph, but the third sounds like a good strategy for getting rid of repeat customers.

Comment: @quid I'd assume that an oil reseller will have their own large storage tanks to deliver their customers from. The company would estimate how often these need to be refilled (e.g. twice per month) and would buy future contracts for those times well ahead of time. Thus, it would not be future contract prices at arbitrary times that matter to them, but only those for which the company has already bought contracts. From the perspective of the company selling you oil, their costs wouldn't change between two of these delivery dates.

Comment: Lot of assumptions…

Comment: @quid sure, but then the OP was asking for **possible** reasons, not for guarantees. I am making the point that it is **possible** for a heating oil rep to know relatively precisely *today* what the costs to buy oil from them will be several months from now.

Comment: @Dreamer, then you should really write it as an answer. It’s a huge leap to assume a sales rep would have intimate knowledge of price hedging.  The same way you wouldn’t assume the clerk at a gas station knows what the price of a gallon of gas will be in several weeks.  And even if the rep knows his cost will be lower in several weeks there is no rational basis to discourage a sale today at todays price, sales people get paid for selling.

Comment: @PastychomperthanksMonica Yes, that's the point. OP should maybe not patronize them if he has other options.

Answer (score 0):

When prices are up due to political events that can reverse suddenly (such as a war), then prices can collapse when that event is over. Wars can cut off oil supplies and make transport of the commodity more risky to ensure. Wars can also end, and with their ends come lower prices.

If one can put the blame on a government for inflating the money supply, then one can expect prices of oil to keep rising.

Comment: Both factors are in play, as well as at least one more with comparable effect - post-covid oil consumption rise. Drillers and especially refineries are not capable of expanding the production quickly enough.

Answer (score 0):

I study investments, and I should say, heating oil is one of investments with highest volatility, because long shelf life and large request fluctuations.

I'm not deep enough to suggest you strategy, but looks like person, you spoke to, right, that current prices much higher than usual.

But as Ukrainian, I could also say, Russian invasion could last to end of year or even more, and all this time prices will be high, because Russia is one of the largest oil exporters in the world, and EU/US/UK issue sanctions to Russian oil export, and their huge energy demand, will supplied from other sources.

Things are so serious, that now considered even reopen some coal power plants.